# Validation generator in Autoencoder returning NaN

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, autoencoder

I am trying to build a fairly simple autoencoder using Keras on the OpenImages dataset. Here is the architecture of the ae:

```
    Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv3d_1 (SeparableConv2D)   (None, 64, 64, 64)        283       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pool_1 (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 32, 32, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_norm_1 (BatchNormaliza (None, 32, 32, 64)        256       
_________________________________________________________________
sep_conv2d_2 (SeparableConv2 (None, 32, 32, 32)        2656      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pool_2 (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 16, 16, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_norm_2 (BatchNormaliza (None, 16, 16, 32)        128       
_________________________________________________________________
sep_conv2d_3 (SeparableConv2 (None, 16, 16, 32)        1344      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pool_3 (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 8, 8, 32)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_norm_3 (BatchNormaliza (None, 8, 8, 32)          128       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 2048)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
bottleneck (Dense)           (None, 64)                131136    
_________________________________________________________________
reshape (Reshape)            (None, 8, 8, 1)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv_2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DT (None, 16, 16, 32)        320       
_________________________________________________________________
batch_norm_4 (BatchNormaliza (None, 16, 16, 32)        128       
_________________________________________________________________
conv_2d_transpose_2 (Conv2DT (None, 32, 32, 32)        9248      
_________________________________________________________________
batch_norm_5 (BatchNormaliza (None, 32, 32, 32)        128       
_________________________________________________________________
conv_2d_transpose_3 (Conv2DT (None, 64, 64, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_norm_6 (BatchNormaliza (None, 64, 64, 64)        256       
_________________________________________________________________
sep_conv2d_4 (SeparableConv2 (None, 64, 64, 3)         771       
=================================================================
Total params: 165,278
Trainable params: 164,766
Non-trainable params: 512
```

I am then defining generators that flow from a directory where I have downloaded the images:

```
train_data_dir = 'open_images/train/'
validation_data_dir = 'open_images/validation/'
batch_size = 128

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode=None)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_data_dir,
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode=None)
```

And here is the model build step:

```
def fixed_generator(generator):
    for batch in generator:
        yield (batch, batch)

num_epochs = 10
steps_per_epoch = 120

autoencoder.fit_generator(
        fixed_generator(train_generator),
        steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
        epochs=num_epochs,
        validation_data=fixed_generator(validation_generator),
        validation_steps=100
        )
```

When I run this code it seems like something is going wrong with the validation step because it only returns NaN:

```
Epoch 1/10
120/120 [==============================] - 241s 2s/step - loss: 0.0468 - val_loss: nan
Epoch 2/10
120/120 [==============================] - 239s 2s/step - loss: 0.0278 - val_loss: nan
Epoch 3/10
120/120 [==============================] - 240s 2s/step - loss: 0.0248 - val_loss: nan
Epoch 4/10
120/120 [==============================] - 241s 2s/step - loss: 0.0234 - val_loss: nan
Epoch 5/10
120/120 [==============================] - 240s 2s/step - loss: 0.0226 - val_loss: nan
Epoch 6/10
120/120 [==============================] - 241s 2s/step - loss: 0.0221 - val_loss: nan
Epoch 7/10
120/120 [==============================] - 242s 2s/step - loss: 0.0217 - val_loss: nan
Epoch 8/10
120/120 [==============================] - 240s 2s/step - loss: 0.0213 - val_loss: nan
Epoch 9/10
120/120 [==============================] - 240s 2s/step - loss: 0.0210 - val_loss: nan
Epoch 10/10
120/120 [==============================] - 242s 2s/step - loss: 0.0207 - val_loss: nan
```

Also when the validation generator code is run it prints:

```
Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes.
```

There are definitely images in that directory though. Any idea what might be going on?

Edit: If you want to be convinced there are images in the folder...

```
ubuntu@ip-172-16-1-35:~$ ls -l open_images/validation/ | head
total 12661044
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   290621 Jul 10  2018 0001eeaf4aed83f9.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   375363 Jul 10  2018 0004886b7d043cfd.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   462817 Jul 10  2018 000595fe6fee6369.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   302326 Jul 10  2018 00075905539074f2.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   970275 Jul 10  2018 0007cebe1b2ba653.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   614095 Jul 10  2018 0007d6cf88afaa4a.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   415082 Jul 10  2018 0008e425fb49a2bf.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   359851 Jul 10  2018 0009bad4d8539bb4.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   186452 Jul 10  2018 000a045a0715d64d.jpg
```

Comment: do you have validation images in "open_images/validation/"? please check that once.

Comment: Thanks @Uday. There are definitely images in that directory. See the edit to my post.

Comment: as per the documentation, It should contain one subdirectory per class. check [this](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/0830affa1f7f19fd47b06d4cf89ed44d)

Comment: Yep @Uday! I just realized this as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please make your data like [this](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/0830affa1f7f19fd47b06d4cf89ed44d) format to work with flow_from_directory.

Comment: Since this is an autoencoder application it shouldn't matter what the folder name is under validation or test correct? It just needs to be there whatever the name.

Comment: Yes, no need for specific folders, you can maintain any one folder and from that, you can get the images data using the flow_from_directory.